# MS Access SQL for UNION from 3 similar tables INSERT INTO a single field in a 4th table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Aim:
Select all distinct values from three different columns, each located in a different table: [QueryA].Att1, [QueryB].Att2, [QueryC].[Att C].
Return all selected values in a single column in a 4th table: [Table1].Field1

The 'INSERT INTO' line isn't working.  The rest of it works (makes query) when 1st line is removed.

The rest of it works (makes query) when 1st line is removed.

```
INSERT INTO [Table1].Field1 

SELECT DISTINCT [QueryA].Att1
FROM [QueryA]

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT [QueryB].Att2
FROM [QueryB] 

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT [QueryC].[Att C]
FROM [QueryC];
```

Error message:

> Syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: Are these Attachment type fields? Attachment type is a multi-value field and normal INSERT action will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, you need to place `UNION` in a subquery or entirely separate query to be included in an append. Additionally, period qualifier between table and column should not be used in `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO [Table1] (Field1)

SELECT Att1 
FROM 
   (SELECT [QueryA].Att1
    FROM [QueryA]

    UNION

    SELECT [QueryB].Att2
    FROM [QueryB] 

    UNION

    SELECT [QueryC].[Att C]
    FROM [QueryC]
  ) AS sub
```

Alternatively, with a separate query:

```
INSERT INTO [Table1] (Field1)    
SELECT Att1 
FROM mySavedUnionQuery
```

Answer (score 1):

could be your insert and select columns don't match  (you have more than a col inf table1)

```
INSERT INTO [Table1] (Field1 )
SELECT  [QueryA].Att1
FROM [QueryA]
UNION
SELECT  [QueryB].Att2
FROM [QueryB] 
UNION
SELECT  [QueryC].[Att C]
FROM [QueryC];
```

and if you use UNION you don't need distinct